# AJAX div content not auto-adjusting page height

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, height, repaint

I have a webpage where a user enters a parameter value, then the result is fetched from server with Ajax and displayed in a `div`. Although the page height is elastic (i.e., supports stretching with sidebars for long content, it does not stretch when the `div` content is updated.

Do I need to call some kind of repaint or refresh method for the page? If yes, which? My page is JQuery enabled too.

**UPDATE**

The page is a Drupal page with full HTML content. According to FireBug, here is the tag with the style:

```
<div id="fw_results_content"
 style="position: absolute;
 top: 25px; width: 450px;
 text-align: justify;"> </div>
```

Comment: Hmmm it should be okay, you got a jsfiddle for it?

Comment: You definetely don't need to call any repaint or refresh methods. You might want to post your code or reproduce the problem on http://jsfiddle.net/, otherwise it's hard to say what the problem might be.

Comment: can your write css style of your container div

Comment: I have updated my question + I am taking a deeper look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely a static height or position problem for the div or one of its parent containers.

If the div or one of its parents has position: fixed or position: absolute, it is omitted from page height calculations.

Likewise, if the div's parent has a static set height, it's height will also be omitted from page height calculations.

**Update**

After reading your updates, it's safe to say the source of your dilemma is

```
style="position: absolute;
```

This tells the browser to ignore the element's height when calculating window height.